# Cannot get React page to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Material-UI to build my app. Here is a link to my code on Github: https://github.com/tutfakulunto/material-ui-site/blob/master/src/modules/languages/index.js and here is the code below:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AppLayout from '../../components/appLayout';
import LanguageIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Language';
import shortid from 'shortid';
import Table, { TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow } from 
    'material-ui/Table';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import {withStyles, withTheme} from 'material-ui/styles';
import api from '../../helpers/api';

class LanguagesPage extends React.Component {

    state = {languages: {}};

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchLanguages()
            .then(languages => this.setState({languages}))
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({languages: {}});
            });
    }

    render() {
        const {languages} = this.state;

        if (!languages.data) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <AppLayout title={[<LanguageIcon className="page-icon" key= 
            {shortid.generate()} />, 'Languages']}>
                <Paper>
                  <Table>
                    <TableHead>
                      <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell numeric>Abbreviation</TableCell>
                        <TableCell numeric>Family</TableCell>
                        <TableCell numeric>Description</TableCell>
                        <TableCell numeric>Created At</TableCell>
                        <TableCell numeric>Updated At</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                   </TableHead>
                   <TableBody>
                      {languages.data.map(language => {
                        return (
                          <TableRow key={language.id}>
                            <TableCell>{language.name}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell numeric>{language.abbreviation} 
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell numeric>{language.family} 
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell numeric>{language.description} 
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell numeric>{language.createdAt} 
                             </TableCell>
                            <TableCell numeric>{language.updatedAt} 
                            </TableCell>
                          </TableRow>
                        );
                      })}
                    </TableBody>
                  </Table>
                </Paper>
            </AppLayout>
        );
    }

        fetchLanguages = () => {
            return api.get('http://localhost:3000/languages');
        }
    }

    export default LanguagesPage;
```

I've commented things out, line by line, and check the Chrome console each time. The console gives me an error saying this:

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually
>   means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the
>   LanguagesPage component.

Naturally, I did check the code, but still can't seem to find why it's not working. Under the network tab, it shows `204 No Content`. If I comment out everything under `render()` and just put Hello World in h1 tags, then it does display the page. This leads me to conclude there's something wrong with my code under `render()`. But then the console error tells me different.

I'd appreciate any advice on this. I'm also relatively new to stack overflow, so please let me know if I should have posted this elsewhere on the site.

Comment: does returning `<div />` like this: `if (!languages.data) {
            return <div />;
        }` instead of `null` help?

Comment: Thanks for anyone who looked at this. I seem to have the problem fixed now.

Comment: @ChesterScottJohnson what . was the issue?

Comment: If it's fixed, please write an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your component may have been mounted and then unmounted before the fetch completed.

To solve this, have a look at this [answer about the same warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50154039/391615)