# Are there semaphores for atomic operations in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atomic

Recently I came across the issue of `fetch()` and `setState()` return to an unmounted component, resulting in an error.
I am looking for a simple solution that does not involve redux or cancelling fetch().

A partial solution might be to use a local variable `this._isMounted` that is set to true at `componentDidMount` and false at `componentWillUnMount`

Now, if you perform:

```
if (this._isMounted) setState({whatever})
```

This is almost complete.
The hole is the period of time, after the condition check and until setState() completes.
Is there a way, by means of semaphores to handle this issue.

For example, delay `componentWillUnmount` access to `this._isMounted`, by waiting for `setState()` semaphore?

Delay may sound bad and not be appropriate in some cases, but semaphores and legacy operating systems solution do seem relevant where async operations take place IMO.

Comment: "I came across the issue of fetch() and setState() return to an unmounted component, resulting in an error."  Can you share more about your component and the error?

Comment: I am referring to a general issue, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount

Comment: "The hole is the period of time, after the condition check and until setState() completes."  There's no opportunity for anything to happen between the test and setState().  There's a single JavaScript thread.

Comment: Single but handles async. calls, please look at https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3
So at that time, until setState() completes & returns, the user can move away from the component, resulting in an unmount prior to setState completion

Comment: If you are looking for a JavaScript semphore, check out [Semaphores in JavaScript](https://medium.com/swlh/semaphores-in-javascript-e415b0d684bc)