# How to use componentWillUnmount in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
  componentDidMount () {
        this.showPosts();
  }

  showPosts = async () => {

    var userID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID');

    fetch(strings.baseUri+"getPostWithUserID", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            "user_id": userID
        })
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

          this.setState({show: false}); // If I comment this line, then I don't get the warning.

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
  }
```

How to use componentWillUnmount because I'm getting the warning below.
Is there a way I can setState show to true when I use componentWillUnmount?
[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM1nd.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel a fetch on componentWillUnmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount)

Comment: @Andrew is it possible if you could give an answer in my scenario? I'm not able to understand on how to use what's given in the link you provided. TIA :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing a couple of things in your code. You are using await but not calling await when you use `this.showPosts()`. You are also not wrapping your `await` in a `try/catch` as `await` can throw.

There a couple of ways that you can solve the problem of setting state on an unmounted component. The most simplest, though it is an anti-pattern is to do is to set a variable in the `componentDidMount` and the `componentWillUnmount` that tracks the mounted state of the component.

So let's refactor your code so that it makes more sense

This is how your `componentDidMount` and the `componentWillUnmount` will now look.

```
async componentDidMount () {
  this._isMounted = true;
  await this.showPosts();
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  this._isMounted = false;
}
```

Updating `showPosts` so that it is purely `async/await`

```
showPosts = async () => {
  try {
    var userID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID');
    let response = await fetch(strings.baseUri + 'getPostWithUserID', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'user_id': userID
      })
    });

    let responseJson = await response.json();
    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.setState({show: false});
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Or if we use your current implementation of showPosts it would look like this, but fixing the lack of try/catch around the await.

```
showPosts = async () => {
  try {
    var userID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID');

    fetch(strings.baseUri + 'getPostWithUserID', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'user_id': userID
      })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
          this.setState({show: false}); // If I comment this line, then I don't get the warning.
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}
```

An alternative is to get into cancelling promises once they have been made. This article goes someway to explaining how to do it https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH  @Andrew. It finally worked for me. But I've a question, why did we make the variable using `this._isMounted`. I mean can you please tell me where it is written that you make variable this way.

Comment: Also I just checked that **isMounted before calling setState() does eliminate the warning**. So the solution you gave me, is it the right way or a hack?

Comment: `this.isMounted()` is deprecated and will be removed at some time in the future.  Best not to use deprecated functions.

Comment: no I mean the overall solution is it the right way? Because the article said that  `if (this.isMounted()) { this.setState({ }) }`  this eliminates the warning

Comment: Yes it is a valid solution. The article says:  *An easy migration strategy for anyone upgrading their code to avoid isMounted() is to track the mounted status yourself. Just set a _isMounted property to true in componentDidMount and set it to false in componentWillUnmount, and use this variable to check your component’s status.* So what we have done is avoided using a deprecated API and used a solution that works.

Comment: @ShubhamBisht I don't use `react-native-video`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if component is mounted this way, and then check this variable inside your async function to see if you can still running the function or otherwise to cancel it:

```
componentDidMount() { 
  this.mounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.mounted = false;
}

async asyncFunction {
  if(this.isMounted){
    setState(....);
  }else{
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: the question is how to prevent setting state in async operation if component is unmounted - so still relevant I would say

Comment: @Mtg Kha Jeskai yes I know that.Is there anyway I can prevent this warning?

Comment: here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount you have possible ways to prevent it

Comment: `if(this.isMounted)` should be exactly befor `setState` not before fetch

Comment: It gives me a warning that isMounted is deprecated.

Comment: Oh, so isMounted is a reserved word? Try with "this.myComponentIsMounted", probably it would work.

Comment: I don't think `myComponentIsMounted` is any reserved word

Comment: That's the reason I told you to use it, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use some internal component object property as - `isComponentMounted` and then check on it during async operation callback.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: you would need to define it by yourself and then control it with lifecycle methods - componentDidMount () { this.isComponentMounted = true }, componentWillUnmount () { this.isComponentMounted = false }

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to set state in componentDidMount without an initial state in the constructor because it triggers an extra render, which can cause performance issues.

From the official documentation:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues. In most cases, you should be able to assign the initial state in the constructor() instead. It can, however, be necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or position.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

But this gets back to WHY you would want to use componentWillUnmount? That is for unregistering events, push notifications, cleaning up resources.