# Data fetching with React hooks cleanup the async callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was starting to build some of my new components with the new and shiny React Hooks. But I was using a lot of async api calls in my components where I also show a loading spinner while the data is fetching. So as far as I understood the concept this should be correct:

```
const InsideCompontent = props => {
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
     ...
     fetchData()
     ...
   },[])

   function fetchData() {
     setFetching(true);
     apiCall().then(() => {
       setFetching(false)
     })
   }
}
```

So this is just my initial idea of how this might work. Just a small example. 
But what happens if the parent component has now a condition changed that this component gets unmounted before the async call is finished.

Is there somehow a check where I can check if the component is still mounted before I call the `setFetching(false)` in the api callback?

Or am I missing something here ?

Here is working example : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/1o0pm2j5yq

EDIT: 
There was no really issue here. You can try it out here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/1o0pm2j5yq

The error was from something else, so with hooks you don't need to check if the component is mounted or not before doing a state change.

Another reason why to use it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel a fetch on componentWillUnmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount)

Comment: @fard no this about react hooks and not the normal react lifecycle methods

Comment: there is no real difference and even answers have been written in hooks

Comment: Could you explicit why cancelling the request won't work for you ? Are you using the data somewhere else ?

Comment: `so with hooks you don't need to cancel the asynchronous callback that's what it does automatically.`

It won't be done automatically, we've gotta take care of cleanup ourselves. (removing event listeners, cancelling network requests, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to store any mutable value you like, so you could use this to toggle a variable `isMounted` to `false` when the component is unmounted, and check if this variable is `true` before you try to update the state.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

function apiCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Foo");
    }, 2000);
  });
}

const InsideCompontent = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ isLoading: true, data: null });
  const isMounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall().then(data => {
      if (isMounted.current) {
        setState({ isLoading: false, data });
      }
    });

    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false
    };
  }, []);
  
  if (state.isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>
  return <div>{state.data}</div>;
};

function App() {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsMounted(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return isMounted ? <InsideCompontent /> : null;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: mh interesting approach. I was using a similar approach for my class components and this would be the equivalent. I somehow thought this could be solved easier with hooks.

Comment: @Tholle Making cancellable promises is easier, clean solution provided by React  guys and it works perfectly with hooks https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5465#issuecomment-157888325

Comment: @fard The `isMounted()` method is an antipattern, yes, but keeping a ref is fine. Introducing a cancellable promise abstraction is overkill is many situations.

Comment: @Tholle im talking about the last section >Ideally, any callbacks should be canceled, prior to unmounting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Hook for fetching data that we use internally. It also allows manipulating the data once it's fetched and will throw out data if another call is made prior to a call finishing.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-data-hook

(You can also just [include the code](https://github.com/liamross/use-data-hook/blob/master/src/useData.ts) if you don't want an entire package)

^ Also this converts to JavaScript by simply removing the types.

It is loosely inspired by [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/), but with more capabilities, so if you don't need the data-manipulation you can always use the solution in that article.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that this is the error you've encountered:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

React complains and hints you at the same time. If component has to be unmounted but there is an outstanding network request, it should be cancelled. Returning a function from within `useEffect` is a mechanism for performing any sort of cleanup required ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)).

Building on your example with `setTimeout`:

```
const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setFetching(false);
    }, 4000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timerId)
  })
```

In case component unmounts before the callback fires, timer is cleared and `setFetching` won't be invoked.

Comment: The timeout was only for mocking a api request time. But thanks

Comment: Yeah that’s clear, I just wanted to demonstrate how to arrange for a cleanup in this case.