# How to cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous task in the componentWillUnmount in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I navigate between two screen success but It always shows warning me below:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method
>
> in Alert (at AwesomeAlert.js:7)
>
> in AwesomeAlert (at LoadingDialog.js:7)
>
> in LoadingDialog (at LoginScreen.js:180)

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a a boolean state flag on mount (`isMounted` or similar) and then set it to `false` in `componentWillUnmount`. Check this flag before calling the function(s) that are raising this warning.

Comment: While this works, [isMounted is an antipattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html). Better to clean up tasks specifically and use AbortController

Comment: Point of order, `isMounted()` is an antipattern, using a property is a suggested migration path away from it: "Just set a _isMounted property to true in componentDidMount and set it to false in componentWillUnmount, and use this variable to check your component’s status"

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Make sure you **have** any **`event listeners, setTimeouts or setIntervals`** in **`componentDidMount`** and remove them in **`componentWillUnmount`**

Example for listeners, setTimeouts and setIntervals:

```
componentDidMount() {

  this.myTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    // someCode here
  }, 7000);

  AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}


componentWillUnmount() {

   AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
   clearTimeout(this.myTimer);

}
```

**2)** To cancel a fetch you have the following options:

**Option A:** Use `AbortController`

(In my opinion AbortController is much better than the old solution with `isMounted` variable)

AbortController example:

```
import "abortcontroller-polyfill"; // in RN 0.60+ this will probably not be needed anymore

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        const AbortController = window.AbortController;
        this.controller = new AbortController();
        this.signal = this.controller.signal;
    }
componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://myurl.com";
    const signal = this.signal;

    fetch(url, { signal })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(err => {
        // You can catch the error
        // thrown by the polyfill here.
        if (err.name == "AbortError") {
            console.log("Fetch Aborted");
        } else {
           //Catch other errors.
        }
    });
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.controller.abort();
}
/*--Rest of the code.--*/
```

}

**Option B:** Use `Axios` and trigger a cancellation in `componentDidMount`

https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

Sources:

AbortController code:
 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18115#issuecomment-420766665

[How to cancel a fetch on componentWillUnmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController

Comment: This way abort promise before my setState() call in componentDidMount and i have emty state(unusable).