# mapStateToProps causes strange warning in top most element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I recently added a mapStateToProps in my top level element:  As you can see I have two conditional renderings that might be causing the issue ...

... yes SO, this is mostly code, supposedly setState is causing a warning for some reason ...

**App**

```
  // ... snip ... inside React class
  render () {
    return (
      <div id='app_hold'>
        <F1Apex/>
        {this.props.App.current && <FastApp/>}
        {!this.props.App.current && <FaviconApp/>}          
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    App: state.App
  }
}
const AppRedux = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRedux></AppRedux>
  </Provider>
, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and am now getting a warning:

[image: r]

**FastApp**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './FastApp.css';

class FastApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      greeting: 'Hello ',
      time: '00:00:00 AM',
      image: 'none'
    }
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    this.setImageAndGreet(); // calls setState()
    this.showTime();  // calls setState()
  }

  // ... snip 

  render () {} // uses this.state which was set by this.setState()
```

Comment: You should connect your App to redux inside the App component, not in your index.js. There are race conditions in your code.

Comment: You are using react's state somewhere (not redux state). The shared code will not help to find your issue

Comment: You are connecting your App component to redux before ReactDom actually renders your component.

Comment: Your warning shows that the issue is located in your FastApp component, can you share it ?

Comment: @Sun-FE please, find where you are using `setState`. The issue is there. No issue in redux here

Comment: I don't see any `setState`... raise my hands

Comment: @LiJonas - you were just guessing .... wrong unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing an async operation in `setImageAndGreet` or `showTime` methods, then updating the state.

The issue is that your `FastApp` component mounts, launches the async methods then unmounts before the promises are resolved because `App.current`'s value have switched to false in that time.

To resolve this you have to cancel your async operations in `componentWillUnmount` method of `FastApp`, or move the logic in the parent component or in redux.

I recommend to read this post about how to [cancel a fetch call in componentWillUnmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount)

Edit: Here's how to cancel setTimeout :

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Timer declaration
    this.myTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ someState: 'someValue' });
      this.myTimer = 0;
    }, 1000);
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Cancel timer if exists
    if (this.myTimer) {
        clearTimeout(this.myTimer);
        this.myTimer = 0;
    }
  };
```

If you use `setTimeout` every second you must use `setInterval` instead, example :

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Timer declaration
    this.myTimer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ someState: 'someValue' });
    }, 1000);
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.myTimer);
  };
```

Comment: Is is a setTimeout that fires every second ... did not really need that warning.

Comment: annoying I can just cancel it in the unmount ... did not realize that conditional render caused an unmount ...

Comment: @Sun-FE I edited my answer with additional informations