# reactJs page redirect

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am getting data with API using React. But when I redirect, I get an error, can you help?
Thank you so much.

Very thanks

```
componentDidMount() {
       fetch(`${this.domain}/api/debt/list?customer=` + this.props.customerInfo.customer.ID, {
           headers: {
               Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('id_token')}`,
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
           }
       })
           .then(res => {
               if (res.ok) {
                   return res.json();
               } else {
                   return res.json().then(err => Promise.reject(err));
               }
           })
           .then(json => {
               this.setState({
                   items: json
               });
               // console.log(json)
           })
           .catch(error => {
               //console.log('request failed:', error);
               return error;
           });
   }

   render() {
     const { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

     if (this.props.customerInfo.customer.ID === "-1") {
           return <Redirect to={"/customerlist"}/>
     }
```

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in AuthWrapped (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at DefaultLayout.js:73)
    in Route (at DefaultLayout.js:68)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel a fetch on componentWillUnmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount)

Comment: Redirect is causing your component to unmount before the fetch is finished. You need to add a componentWillUnmount method and cancel your fetch it in. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount/53435967#53435967) about using the AbortController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this happens when you have `this.props.customerInfo.customer.ID === "-1"` true. In this case, you are redirecting, but the API call you made is still pending and upon it's completion you are using `setState` on a component which does not exist since you already redirected.

1) Easiest way to fix this is before using `setState` put a conditional check for the case in which you have redirected or better you have a separate flag to check this.

```
constructor(){
    this.isComponentDestroyed = false;
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch(...)
    .then(()=>{
        if(!this.isComponentDestroyed){
            this.setState({
                items: json
            });
        }
    })
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    this.isComponentDestroyed = true;
}
```

2) You can also check on how to cancel the `fetch` call. Ref [How do I cancel an HTTP fetch() request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request)

---

From the comments, adding a reference to [How to cancel a fetch on componentWillUnmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount)