# Poll API until a path in the response object is Successful | Failure - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, settimeout

I have a function which accepts a string and a path value and checks whether the path at the result returns a 1 or a -1. I fire the function with multiple requests and everything seems to be successful except for one. For example, if I call the function with 10 different URL's continously (one by one, not in an array), the promise is resolved for 9 but not for the 10th one.

This is my code:

```
enum Status {
  Queued = 0,
  Started = 1,
  Finished = 2,
  Failed = -1,
}

let dataFetchingTimer: number;

export const getDataAtIntervals = (url: string, path: string): Promise<any> => {
  clearTimeout(dataFetchingTimer);
  return new Promise<any>((resolve: Function, reject: Function): void => {
    try {
      (async function loop() {
        const result = await API.load(url);
        console.log(`${url} - ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
        if (
          get(result, path) &&
          (get(result, path) === Status.Finished ||
            get(result, path) === Status.Failed)
        ) {
          return resolve(result); // Resolve with the data
        }
        dataFetchingTimer = window.setTimeout(loop, 2500);
      })();
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
};

export const clearGetDataAtIntervals = () => clearTimeout(dataFetchingTimer);
```

[image]

Please advice. In the above image, 4535 is called only once. and is not called until 2 or -1 is returned.

Comment: Not easy to say without being able to run it, but my guess is that it has something to do with all requests sharing the same `dataFetchingTimer` variable. It's unclear how you call it, or what your output corresponds to

Comment: I call it as const result = await getDataAtIntervals(url, “status”). Setstate(oldState=> {return {data: {...oldState.data, result}}})

Comment: Can i create multiple settimeout?

Comment: I guess so. I'm not used to Typescript, so I used JS, but this might give you an idea of something possible: https://jsfiddle.net/gx3t8d0e/

Comment: @blex thank you. Will try out and let you know

Comment: It works man. Thanks a lot. U're the best.

Comment: Cool! I'll post it as an answer then

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single timeout for all your calls might be the cause of weird behaviors. A solution to avoid collisions between your calls might be to use a timeout per call. You could do something along these lines *(I used simple JS because I'm not used to Typescript)*:

```
const Status = {
  Queued: 0,
  Started: 1,
  Finished: 2,
  Failed: -1,
}

let dataFetchingTimerMap = {
  // Will contain data like this:
  // "uploads/4541_status": 36,
};

const setDataFetchingTimer = (key, cb, delay) => {
  // Save the timeout with a key
  dataFetchingTimerMap[key] = window.setTimeout(() => {
    clearDataFetchingTimer(key); // Delete key when it executes
    cb(); // Execute the callback
  }, delay);
}

const clearDataFetchingTimer = (key) => {
  // Clear the timeout
  clearTimeout(dataFetchingTimerMap[key]);
  // Delete the key
  delete dataFetchingTimerMap[key];
}

const getDataAtIntervals = (url, path) => {
  // Create a key for the timeout
  const timerKey = `${url}_${path}`;
  // Clear it making sure you're only clearing this one (by key)
  clearDataFetchingTimer(timerKey);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // A try/catch is useless here (https://jsfiddle.net/4wpezauc/)
    (async function loop() {
      // It should be here (https://jsfiddle.net/4wpezauc/2/)
      try {
        const result = await API.load(url);
        console.log(`${url} - ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
        if ([Status.Finished, Status.Failed].includes(get(result, path))) {
          return resolve(result); // Resolve with the data
        }
        // Create your timeout and save it with its key
        setDataFetchingTimer(timerKey, loop, 2500);
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    })();
  });
};

const clearGetDataAtIntervals = () => {
  // Clear every timeout
  Object.keys(dataFetchingTimerMap).forEach(clearDataFetchingTimer);
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep getting the data and updating the react state until the promise is resolved?