# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component in react

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue when I try to get data api from my mongoose

Here is my code:

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const getProductsAPI = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/products")
      .then((res) => {
        setProducts(res.data);
        getProductsAPI();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductsAPI();
  }, [props]);
```

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
> a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
> function.

Comment: have you tried using a `setTimeout` within your promise handler?

Comment: I haven't. How can i setTimeout for that ?

Comment: Can you explain why are you invoking `getProductsAPI()` right after setting the product state?

Comment: After reading the post from Danilo below, I would go with that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the network request is resolved after the component unmounts. You can probably try some solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount) thread.