# Unhandled Rejection (AbortError): The operation was aborted

Tags: reactjs, fetch, request-cancelling

EDIT: react app crash only in firefox. when im using chrome, react app not crash. How to handle crash in firefox?

I want to cancel http request when component is unmounted. Im using fetch() and AbortController.

Im following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49906662/11241731).

But when component unmounted, react app is crash.

[image]

this is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import AbortController from "abort-controller"

function Label(){
  const abortController = new AbortController()
  const signal = abortController.signal
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      async function getLabels(){
          const req = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/label`, {
              credentials: 'include',
              signal: signal
          })
          const res = await req.json()
        
          setLabels(res.data)
      }
    
      getLabels()
    
      // cancel httprequest if component unmounted
      return function cancel(){
          abortController.abort()
      }
  }, [])


return (<p>ehehe</p>)

}
```

Comment: As per the documentation, calling abort will cause the fetch promise to be rejected. Can you try wrapping fetch call in a try/catch ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Note: When abort() is called, the fetch() promise rejects with an Error of type DOMException, with name AbortError.

So you are getting the exception because infact you call `abort` on fetch. I would suggest to modify your `useEffect` in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
      async function getLabels(){
          try {
             const req = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/label`, {
              credentials: 'include',
              signal: signal
             })
             const res = await req.json()
        
             setLabels(res.data)
          }
          catch(error) {
             if (error.name === "AbortError") return;
             console.log("Error ", error);
          }
      }
    
      getLabels()
    
      // cancel httprequest if component unmounted
      return function cancel(){
          abortController.abort()
      }
  }, [])
```

Comment: I tried this solution to fix my problem but still got the error mentioned in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993905/react-js-use-abort-controller-outside-useeffect?noredirect=1#comment128923292_72993905

Comment: @user3476614 lets continue this chat in your ticket...  I posted a comment