# React js use Abort controller outside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, request-cancelling, abortcontroller

I have a component where an abort controller is declared outside a `useEffect`. `controller.abort()` is called inside a `useEffect` when the component is unmounted.

When the component is unmounted this error below is thrown

**Unhandled Rejection (AbortError): The operation was aborted.**

```
 const controller = new AbortController()
    function MyComponent() {

      useEffect(() => {
        return () => controller.abort()
      }, [])
    
    const fetchData = async () => {
         try {
         const data = await fetchMyData(controller)
    } catch(error) {
    if (error.name === "AbortError") return
      console.log("Error ", error)
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

stacktrace images

[image]

Comment: Where is `fetchData` called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled Rejection (AbortError): The operation was aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69007006/unhandled-rejection-aborterror-the-operation-was-aborted)

Comment: No. When `controller.abort()` is called the error Unhandled Rejection (AbortError): The operation was aborted. Is still thrown

Comment: did the `catch(error)` print something?

Comment: No, it does not even go `catch(error)` section. The app crashes the app crashes Unhandled Rejection (AbortError): The operation was aborted. I don't know if the error is coming from my react code or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73237571/handle-domexception-in-a-promise

Comment: Oh ok... well just to be 100% sure: did you try to wrap `controller.abort()` into `{}` brackets?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I still have the same problem. I updated the question with images if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Check your index.js in root. If you are using StrictMode, that is exactly the problem. Checkout document: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html.
I think what you should do here is call request and abort in the same one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions from both of your tickets (this one and this of [Unhandled Rejection (AbortError): The operation was aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69007006/unhandled-rejection-aborterror-the-operation-was-aborted) ). I tried Abortcontroller, cleanup after useEffect as well as try/catch, but it didn't come to the catch section at all. What worked for me was adding another catch in the try-area, basically, after the handling of the promise.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    try {
      loadOptions()
        .then((response) => ...)
       // The error is catched here
        .catch((error) => console.log("Error"));
    } catch (error) {
      // It didn't work, as it never comes to this section
      console.log('Error ');
    }
  }, [item]);
```

So the error is catched and the app is not chashed. However, in my case, it is not really a good solution, as it seems to be a bug in new version of Apollo (as mentioned here [DOMException: signal is aborted without reason in useEffect with async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75242951/domexception-signal-is-aborted-without-reason-in-useeffect-with-async-call) ) and it should be handled more properly.