# DOMException: signal is aborted without reason in useEffect with async call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, signals

I have a project using React in Strict Mode alongside GraphQL.

I updated some packages, and I now get the following error in useEffect containing async calls.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadTags = async () => {
      const { data } = await fetchTags();
      setTags([...(data?.tags || [])]);
    };

    loadTags();
  }, [current, fetchTags]);
```

> DOMException: signal is aborted without reason in useEffect with async call.

I am not quite sure what is causing this, I believe the use effect rerun and clear itself up, and it doesn't abort the query properly.

This didn't happen previously, or at least didn't produce an error.

I am wondering if my implementation if incorrect, or if some package I updated go an issue, I couldn't find any relevant thread on github on the package I updated

Answer (score 5):

I have also the same issue after upgrading the `@apollo/client` library from version `3.7.1` to `3.7.8`, when using `useLazyQuery` (probably the same with `useQuery`).

**The bug was introduced with version `3.7.4`.**

Until a fix is provided by Apollo, the solution is to **downgrade to version <= `3.7.3`.**

Here is the stack trace (for reference):

```
useLazyQuery.ts:78 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: signal is aborted without reason
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@apollo_client.js?v=d5c2e0d9:8702:20
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@apollo_client.js?v=d5c2e0d9:8701:35
    at safelyCallDestroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-JZ3YVIXN.js?v=8247418e:16737:13)
    at commitHookEffectListUnmount (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-JZ3YVIXN.js?v=8247418e:16864:19)
    at invokePassiveEffectUnmountInDEV (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-JZ3YVIXN.js?v=8247418e:18359:19)
    at invokeEffectsInDev (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-JZ3YVIXN.js?v=8247418e:19697:19)
    at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-JZ3YVIXN.js?v=8247418e:19678:15)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-JZ3YVIXN.js?v=8247418e:19499:13)
    at flushPassiveEffects (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-JZ3YVIXN.js?v=8247418e:19443:22)
```

Comment: Do you have link to the issue?

Comment: @BMH there is [a similar issue here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/10520) in the Apollo Client GitHub repository.

Comment: By the way, this issue only happens when StrictMode is enabled. As explained by jerelmiller in above link, a temporary solution is to create a custom hook that extends `useLazyQuery`, wrap everything in try/catch, and not raise an error for `AbortError`. However, it's not a great solution. For me, it's clearly a bug and a breaking change because it was working fine with version `<= 3.7.3`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is a Next JS project, I set the reactStrictMode of the next.config.js file to false and it ran normally with version 3.7.10

```
 /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true
  },
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```